# Perl MongoDB insert error msg

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have this following database this is an object already in the database

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("001"), "password" : "test", "user" : "test"}
```

Things add to that collection

1.index over user and password

2.Unique index over user

When i try to inssert the same parameters into the items

```
my $enter = $db->data->insert({'user'=>'test','password'=>'test'});
```

$enter returns a value of a ObjectID(if user is repeated it should get a error msg rather than a Objectid)

Through mongo shell

E11000 duplicate key error index: dataofitem.user

its showing error but when i try through Perl module (https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB)

it was returned as an object id, i was wondering why i did't got the error msg instead of Objectid

Comment: Would you show your code please and the error message you mentioned?

Comment: @mugenkenichi added some more info check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB::Collection::insert does not check for errors.

Try

```
my $enter = $db->data->insert({'user'=>'test','password'=>'test'}, {safe => 1});
```

to make the module croak on failure. This is documented in [MongoDB::Collection](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aCollection#insert-object-options-)

If you want to check for errors you can also do

```
my $error = $db->last_error();
```

as documented [here](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB%3a%3aDatabase#last_error-options-).

Comment: If safe is true, croak comes into play it just kills the process, How pass the error to a string

Comment: As I already answered you can check with `last_error` if you do not use `{safe => 1}`.